# If a player dies and I have no resurrection scrolls (or spells that do the same), what are my options?

Tags: divinity-original-sin-2

Right now my friends and me are pretty early in the game, so the scrolls are plentiful, but I really wonder: if we die a lot and spend them all, what happens next? If a player dies, well, that player can go grab himself a beer because he will not be able to play until we find a scroll, or is there other, probably longer to do, options to revive a player without a scroll or a spell?

(I should add we are playing tactician mode, which is if I remember right the hardest difficulty before the ironman type modes. A lot of deaths are thus expected.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know There is no Resurrect spell you can learn, only scrolls. I know With Necromancy you can learn Last Rites, it will be sold in stores after reaching level 16. This spell does piercing damage to the caster and revives another. Other then that I think it's just scrolls.

Comment: Just stock up on scrolls whenever you can or save scum :P

Comment: Yeah we are still in the Fort Joy part of the game... Scrolls cost 1k and our mere 200g is not enough. I guess its gonna get to a point where 1k is not that much, or I need to boost bartering.

Comment: But yeah at the end of the day: If one of my friends falls in battle, well, go take a nap because for the next hour you are dead?

Comment: @Fredy31 yep XD

Comment: I smell some save scrubbing in the future when we got no scrolls and even one of us dies :p

Comment: @Fredy31 GL!!!!

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your progress through the story, you may have varying access to the ingredients you need to craft scrolls (water essence, life essence, sheet of paper).

- Essences are sometimes sold by merchants, though they can also get quite expensive if you don't have Thievery
- Some enemies have a chance to drop essence as loot, though water/life may not be as common as you'd like in the early game
- Gather wood chips by whittling wood (combine a dagger with logs/branches/short sticks), combine wood chips with water to make wood pulp, and bake wood pulp in an oven to make paper
- Paper can sometimes be found on shelves or among "rows of books" in the environment
- Book containers have a chance to contain resurrection scrolls

If you often find yourself hurting for cash, you can make a decent living by collecting items off the ground - particularly silverware, paintings, and ingredients - and selling them, or crafting with them to potentially make more valuable items to be sold.

You can also consider enabling the *From the Ashes* mod from one of the Larian Gift Bags, which lets you resurrect nearby party members to full health by using a bedroll in the vicinity of their soul/corpse, but only outside of combat. If your deceased companion is not far enough away from hostiles, it will be unsafe to rest, but you can move the body as needed if anyone in your party has Teleportation. (Enabling this mod also disables achievements.)